# Combine 2 Java web applications

Tags: java, maven, web-applications

Suppose you have 2 (or more) Java web projects (Java 6, maven) that you need to release as 1 web application (currently Servlet 2.5 & Tomcat 6)?

How to develop these 2 project, that then they can be combined easier? What are frameworks and tools that work together well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven war plugin can do [overlays](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html). [Example.](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/war-overlay.html) This would be good for inclusion of web resources, but not web.xml

Also there is [cargo-maven2-plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Merging+WAR+files), that additionally can merge web.xml content.

Answer (score 1):

If you are forced to bundle the different web projects before deploying I personally would consider to create only a single repository which is managed e.g. by Git or SVN.
This single repository stores all your projects as one archive and not as single projects.

This way every developer can take of his project which in this case would only be a package. After development is finished you can simply release a WAR file from this repository without bothering about how to integrate the different projects.

But I'm sure the described solution has also disadvantages but it would be my first idea for your question.

Comment: I agree these related project should be in one SCM folder, and changes committed together.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to package the two web applications as an EAR which can be deployed to a full EE server.
For this you could create a separate maven project which will do the assembly.

This being said, tomcat is not a full EE server.  You can only deploy WARs.
So you might need to look at some war-overlay techniques but I find those difficult to use and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can use [the maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/), which is support assembly the war distribution:
Currently it can create distributions in the following formats:

- zip
- tar
- tar.gz
- tar.bz2
- jar
- dir
- war
- and any other format that the ArchiveManager has been configured for

An alternative is [maven-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/), this will packaging and assembly the webapp, but this need to add the dependency of the two webapps.

Comment: I think it is wrong advice. First, only .war is needed. Second, it will not help to combine 2 web app into 1 web app.

Comment: Did you see this link [Multi-Module Examples](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/multimodule/index.html)